# How to exit nodemon on a windows

Tags: node.js

I´am on a windows machine, and I understand that it is a little different here.

The problem is that I can't find any information on how I stop, kill or exit nodemon.

Comment: Does a simple ctr+c not work?

Comment: You can kill it from the task manager.

Comment: Can someone post/accept an answer, or close this question.  Preferably just close it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For purposes of completeness, The correct answer is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Or you could also find it in task manager and kill it. This applies to pretty much anything on the command line.

Comment: This leaves the process started by nodemon behind.

Comment: Using Cmder, the process left behind by nodemon interferes with the shell. Instead, use 'Terminate (kill) all but shell processes in the current console' found in hotkey settings

Answer (score 25):

My experience here is that Ctrl+C leaves a node instance running in the background. If you want to kill the stack, when you try to restart 'nodemon server.js' or just 'node server.js' for that matter, you will get an EADDRINUSE error because the old node server has the port tied up. You have to find it by using `ps -W | grep node` in the terminal window, because the task manager wont show it. Also you can kill it with the process ID (PID) with taskkill. The /F is the 'force' parameter. Here we will kill the task with PID 7528.

```
$ taskkill /F /PID 7528
```

Then check ps -W | grep node again, and the node server should be gone, and the server will launch again.

Their docs show a few tricks on intercepting the shutdown command, but since they use a 'rs' command to restart, they could add a 'kill' command to shutdown the daemon.

Brian

Comment: For me, on Windows 10 running "Git Bash for Windows", I had to type "taskkill -F -PID ####" to kill the process. Instead of "/F /PID"

Comment: Or better yet just use `taskkill /F /IM node.exe`, you do not need to find any PID in this case.

Comment: this answer solved my problem as well. By far should be top voted and the accepeted answer. taskkill -F -PID #### did the trick!!

Answer (score 2):

I used git bash on window and I couldn't terminate the nodemon process with `ctr` + `c`, so I would terminate the node process on the task manager to use the same port. Later I found on [github](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1109) to why `nodemon` doesn't terminate in `git bash`. Anyway`powershell` should be use instead, after `ctr` + `c` it will ask either to terminate batch job or not. This action will clear the process and stop nodemon.

Answer (score 2):

With the keys ctrl + c
With this you can get out of our nodemon

Or with this you can prevent the module from continuing to work

```
process.exit(1);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer did not add any new information to other answers in the post. Next time try to include more relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Go to --> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin.
In bin folder there is windows-kill.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this until I ran command prompt as an administrator. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> worked.

**EDIT:** Sorry, the above worked once and then stopped working. I did end up finding this article: http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/how-kill-running-nodejs-processes-in-windows . The command provided here (taskkill /im node.exe /F) works consistently for me on Windows, when I run it in a new command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + C to exit from Nodemon on windows. If that does not work, simply end the task from task manager and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

type .exit (it worked in my case)